# How to get list of all .NET assemblies programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, .net-assembly

I have an application to write *dynamic assembly* in runtime, so I need to a list of all assemblies in my system like Visual Studio **Reference Manager**:

[image: Reference Manager]

My question is: How to fetch a list of all **.NET Assemblies** by self `.NET` languages and without searching a folder files?

**Note:** 
I know I can find any assemblies from: 
`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\...`  
 
or  
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`
but I not sure to find that assemblies in all system by this way! 
Because I do not have access to these folders on all computers. So my app only through .NET code can fetch the names of these assemblies. And other problem is that the path to this folder on all the computers are not fixed and may vary.

Comment: You can use the Fusion APIs. Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430568/A-GAC-Manager-Utility-and-API it gives a class that wraps the COM objects into a nice .NET library to get the list.

Comment: Why don't you want to read folders and files? How do you think it could work if not searching folders and files?

Comment: @ThomasWeller in fact, I do not have access to these folders on all computers. So my app only through .NET code can fetch the names of these assemblies.
And other problem is that the path to this folder on all the computers are not fixed and may vary.

Comment: Well, that's a good reason and should be documented in the question.

Comment: The reference window in VS is getting assemblies from certain folders. I'm not sure what you mean by "all assemblies in system" - generally assemblies can be located in any folder on your machine. You might check out [this](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012010.aspx) article, but I don't think you can do it without access to the folders.

Comment: @vesan Thanks about [this](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012010.aspx) article, that's very helpful. But I'm still the problem of limited access to Windows drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have a look on GAC Manager project on Codeplex :
https://gacmanager.codeplex.com/
It will be really helpful and nice to use for your purpose. On the project page you'll also find a working sample (not tried with .Net 4.6 by me anyway, hope it works well also for this one)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute gacutil.exe/i command directly from your code to get list of all GAC assemblies. You can see a sample code here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9283b0f-94b7-4fe2-9196-92f81c6e7ba0/obtaining-list-of-assemblies-present-in-gac?forum=clr

Comment: Thanks, But I tested this link codes before ask my question! first this codes didn't work and I want to solve this problem by .NET language not an executable file!

Comment: You don't. There is no reliable way to determine source language from executable file. I have an assembly that is compiled from another assembly by a compiler you have never heard of.

Comment: @Joshua: what is your comment referring to?

Comment: Behzad Khosravifar asked how to get the language each assembly was compiled for.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC Visual Studio simply reads the contents of this directory to display this info:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

As a test, I deleted Accessibility.dll

[image: assemblies]

YMMV

Comment: How do you know it "simply reads" the directory and does not look up contents another way (e.g. via [Fusion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404523%28v=VS.110%29.aspx))?